# Console to jTextArea1 issue. (voids!?)

Tags: java, user-interface, console, void

```
class TreeTraversal
{
  public void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    System.out.println("Displaying the tree");
    theTree.displayTree();
```

/** how to you print these kind of things? e.g theTree.preOrder(theTree.returnRoot()); in to the jTextArea1 ?  */

```
    StringBuilder order1 = new StringBuilder("Inorder traversal: ");
    jTextArea1.append("\n"+order1);
    //System.out.println("Inorder traversal");
    theTree.inOrder(theTree.returnRoot());
    //System.out.println(" ");

    StringBuilder order2 = new StringBuilder("Preorder traversal: ");
    jTextArea1.append("\n"+order2);
    //System.out.println("Preorder traversal");
    theTree.preOrder(theTree.returnRoot());
    //System.out.println(" ");

    StringBuilder order3 = new StringBuilder("Postorder traversal: ");
    jTextArea1.append("\n"+order3);
    //System.out.println("Postorder traversal");
    theTree.postOrder(theTree.returnRoot());
    //System.out.println(" ");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Visitor pattern is suitable for traversing object structures. To learn about visitor see http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html. If this is too complex for you, here is more understandable visitor in java http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

You have to create visitor that prints currently visited node.

To change traversal order you can use what you have (`postOrder,preOrder,inOrder`) or you can make visitor method to return some value. Value should mean noIteration/inOrder/preOrder/postOrder. 
Advantage of this is you can stop/change traversal at any node.